# Codeigniter Days Left mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, days

I have a simple script that displays products. In my database I store both `date_posted` and `end_date` as fields in he products table. On my homepage I display the 20 most recent posted products.

I want to display products that have 1 or more days left. So far I've manage to do this but using the front end script and css and this isn't best practice because it won't display 20 products if some among them have ended.

Below is the script that i have:

my View =>

```
 <?php $i=0;?>
        <?php foreach($product as $p): ?> 
        <?php 
    $startDate = date('m/d/Y');
    $endDate = $p['endDate'];
    $seconds_left = (strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate));
    $days_left = floor($seconds_left / 3600 / 24);


     ?>
       <?php  $i+= 1; ?>

            <td <?php  //if($days_left<=0){echo "class='ended'";} ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url()."user/product/".$p['productID']; ?>" class="product_name"><?php echo $p['productName']; ?>
            </a>
             <ul class="nav">
        <li><i class="icon-home"> </i> Location : <?php echo substr($p['location'],0,25); ?></li>
        <li><i class="icon-tags"> </i> Budget : Tshs <?php  echo number_format($p['Price']); ?></li>
        <li><i class="icon-tasks"> </i> <?php if($p['CategoryID']==4){echo"Number of rooms: ";}else echo "Quantity :"?> <?php echo $p['quantity']; ?></li> 
        <li><i class="icon-eye-open"> </i> Bids : <?php echo $p['Bids']; ?></li>
        <li><i class="icon-time"> </i> Days Left: <?php echo $days_left; ?></li>
      </ul>

            </td>
```

my Model=>

```
 function get_product($productID){
                               $this->db->select()->from('products')->where('productID',$productID);


                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->first_row('array');
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get a date in your where clause.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
function get_product($productID){
          $this->db->select()
             ->from('products')
             ->where('productID',$productID)
             ->where('end_date >=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('- 1 day')))
             ->limit(20);

          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

Comment: thnk you so much @bottleboot,t workd perfectly rily appreciate coz i was stuck on ths for hours,but i only have to change "end_date<=" to "end_date>=" so as t display days greater than 0 in my case so i changed -1 to 0.thnks again buddy :-)

Comment: Oops, my bad, not fully awake yet! I modified my answer.
No problem, glad I could help. You can also accept the answer if you want!